# Blender 2.91 smoke look fuzzy while I want it plain and smooth

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Blender smoke look fuzzy while I want it plain
Hello everyone, it's my first time doing this so I don't really know If I'm doing this right but here is my problem.

I'm trying to simulate a character appearing of a smoke puff and my smoke doesn't look right :
[image]

Blender smoke look fuzzy while I want it plain
see, it's all fuzzy, looking dissipated or like a bunch of dots
here a rendered view,
same problem especially on the bottom left :

[image]

I want it to look plain, full, heavy, smooth, puffy like this :

[image]

or this

[image]

You see ? I think I can provide the file if needed

Comment: try increasing the density

Comment: and providing the blend file is always a good idea...!

Comment: Sorry for being late, I'm being pretty busy rn, where could I provide the file ? I've prepared it

Comment: here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I prevent you, It's very heavy

Comment: use dropbox or something else....or just make your project smaller

Comment: Here is a different file, smaller but with the same problem [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=dzQnkbsO" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/dzQnkbsO/)